# SSAS -> MDX -> Creating a column percentage within my query based on counts

Tags: ssas, mdx

```sql
SELECT
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Fact Order Count]} 
   ON COLUMNS,
   { ([Front Manager].[Front Manager Id].[Front Manager Id].ALLMEMBERS * [Order Type].[Order Type].[Order Type].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
   ON ROWS 
FROM
   [TEST_DW] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

So, I have three columns in the output:

Front Manager, Order Type, Order Count

The above query shows me the counts for each manager and order type combination.  I need a fourth column which would be a percentage of the types of orders for each front manager.

So, if there are four types of orders (A, B, C, D), and a manager had 25 of each order totaling 100.  The fourth column would read 25%.....

I have scoured the web on how to do this, but have really come up short on this one.  Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated, I am definitely new to MDX.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are [MDX Calculated members](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Calculated%20Members.html).

Let's assume the member for order A is called : [Order Type].[Order Type].[Order A] and we want to calculate the percentage from the total.

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Order A] AS ([Order Type].[Order Type].[Order A],[Measures].[Fact Order Count]) / ([Measures].[Fact Order Count]) , FORMAT_STRING = 'Percent'
SELECT
   {[Measures].[Fact Order Count],[Measures].[Order A]} on 0
...
```

What is important in the calculated members is that you can evaluate any MDX tuple (e.g ([Order Type].[Order Type].[Order A],[Measures].[Fact Order Count]) ). This changing if needed the values coming from the pivot axis (defined in on 0 and on 1..). Note you can add calculated members for the measures as well as the other dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the post, sorry I have been sick for a few days unable to comment back.